# changing the background color of <li> looks funny

Tags: javascript, css

I have a li element . if the li element is a single line ,on hovering the backgroud color looks okay but when the li element contains text that is multiline the background color looks somewhat bad.
See the attached screenshot.

```
  #leftNavi li a.current{
color: white;
background: #AD0E3F; 
text-decoration: none;
  }

  #leftNavi li a:hover{
color: white;
background: #AD0E3F;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code? Is your css `line-height` set?

Comment: If you can post code or a demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that's generally better - not everyone has permission to view hosted screenshots.

Comment: tried to fiddle it for you. looks pretty much allright, there must be something else in your css. http://jsfiddle.net/pGHye/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mate just add:

```
#leftNavi li a{display:block;}
```

See example: [http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/5NpAz/](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/b8JPy/)

Comment: Ignor hat its from a previous answer... ill update the fiddle

Comment: Can something be done to the li element instaed of doing it on "a"?

Comment: because i have another a and it's also getting changed with this.

Comment: Make use of IDs and Classes to only add the CSS to the `<a>`s you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another node that wraps the content of the `LI` and put the `:hover` on the `LI` and not the `A`. And make the LI float to avoid to have it full width.

```
<li>
  <div>
    <a class="current" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: +1'ed for :hover on li, that's what I was about to post but out of curiosity what do you mean by wrapping content of li in a node, or rather, why? I am probably misunderstanding a detail in your answer.

Comment: @stefgosselin HAHAHA, im quite anal about stuff working in IE6 as i have to be in my job.